# Como limpar a tela do interpretador de Python do Windows?

Tags: python-3.x, interpretador

Estou começando a estudar Python (versão 3), fazendo vários testes de sintaxe utilizando o interpretador para Windows. Porém, gostaria de limpar da tela os comandos que já executei, à medida que a barra de rolagem vai crescendo. Tentei digitar `clear`, `clean`, `CTRL+L`, mas nada disso funcionou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com base nestas fontes ([fonte1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517970/how-to-clear-the-interpreter-console), [fonte2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810537/how-to-clear-the-screen-in-python)), sendo windows podes fazer:

```
import os
os.system('cls')
```

Se fosse linux seria:

```
import os
os.system('clear')
```

Não testei, mas acredito que resulte

Comment: Funcionou. Mas achei um pouco verboso para um simples comando de clear...

Comment: É verdade também acho, mas é windows :P, vou tentar encontrar alguma alternativa mas duvido que haja uma menos verbosa

Comment: Realmente, não há. Até porque o comando executado pertence ao interpretador, não é nativo ao Python, portanto deve-se utilizar a biblioteca `os`. Lembre-se também que Python é portável: o mesmo código funciona tanto em Windows quanto em Linux, ou outro sistema operacional, então é interessante fazer algo como `os.system('cls' if os.name=='nt' else 'clear')`, pois `cls` funciona no Windows, enquanto `clear` funciona no Linux.

Comment: Acrescentei essa alternativa (sendo linux) à resposta, obgado @AndersonCarlosWoss